# OpenSSL s_client command output to text file

Tags: openssl

Trying to run the below OpenSSL command

```
openssl.exe s_client -connect google.com:443
```

which gives the below output in the beginning on the command prompt

```
CONNECTED(000001D8)
depth=2 C = US, O = Google Trust Services LLC, CN = GTS Root R1
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Google Trust Services LLC, CN = GTS CA 1C3
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = \*.google.com
verify return:1
-

Certificate chain
0 s:CN = \*.google.com
i:C = US, O = Google Trust Services LLC, CN = GTS CA 1C3
a:PKEY: id-ecPublicKey, 256 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA256
v:NotBefore: Nov 28 08:17:11 2022 GMT; NotAfter: Feb 20 08:17:10 2023 GMT
1 s:C = US, O = Google Trust Services LLC, CN = GTS CA 1C3
i:C = US, O = Google Trust Services LLC, CN = GTS Root R1
a:PKEY: rsaEncryption, 2048 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA256
v:NotBefore: Aug 13 00:00:42 2020 GMT; NotAfter: Sep 30 00:00:42 2027 GMT
2 s:C = US, O = Google Trust Services LLC, CN = GTS Root R1
i:C = BE, O = GlobalSign nv-sa, OU = Root CA, CN = GlobalSign Root CA
a:PKEY: rsaEncryption, 4096 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA256
v:NotBefore: Jun 19 00:00:42 2020 GMT; NotAfter: Jan 28 00:00:42 2028 GMT
```

However, when I try to export the output to the text file, the output starts from

```
CONNECTED(000001D4)
-

Certificate chain
0 s:CN = \*.google.com
i:C = US, O = Google Trust Services LLC, CN = GTS CA 1C3
a:PKEY: id-ecPublicKey, 256 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA256
v:NotBefore: Nov 28 08:17:11 2022 GMT; NotAfter: Feb 20 08:17:10 2023 GMT
1 s:C = US, O = Google Trust Services LLC, CN = GTS CA 1C3
i:C = US, O = Google Trust Services LLC, CN = GTS Root R1
a:PKEY: rsaEncryption, 2048 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA256
v:NotBefore: Aug 13 00:00:42 2020 GMT; NotAfter: Sep 30 00:00:42 2027 GMT
2 s:C = US, O = Google Trust Services LLC, CN = GTS Root R1
i:C = BE, O = GlobalSign nv-sa, OU = Root CA, CN = GlobalSign Root CA
a:PKEY: rsaEncryption, 4096 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA256
v:NotBefore: Jun 19 00:00:42 2020 GMT; NotAfter: Jan 28 00:00:42 2028 GMT
```

Need the top most part to also come in the output file but it doesn't which is the below section.

```
depth=2 C = US, O = Google Trust Services LLC, CN = GTS Root R1
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Google Trust Services LLC, CN = GTS CA 1C3
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = \*.google.com
verify return:1
```

How can I capture the entire output to a text file?

The entire top most section of the openssl.exe command output is not captured in the text file.

Comment: *when I try to export the output to the text file,* How do you do it?

Comment: openssl.exe s_client -connect google.com:443 > output.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the missing part is printed to `stderr`, so add `2>&1` at the end

```
openssl.exe s_client -connect google.com:443 > output.txt 2>&1
```

`2>&1` redirects stderr to stdout